# how to implement constraint in table such that inserted values do not repeat for group of rows only

Tags: php, mysql, mysql5

I have to construct a table with columns

***col1(primary key)   col2(not null)  col3(not null)  col4(not null)***

Now I need to insert values into this table such that values inserted into col3 don't repeat for set of values in col2....what are the constraints that is need to implement??...

Values can repeat in col3 as a whole ...But for some set of values of col2 values in col3 need not repeat.
So this is the column name.
**`ID`     `ID_Category` `Keywords` `Score`**

Values in `Keywords` column can repeat - but for some values in `ID_Category`, `Keywords` values need not repeat.
Can you help me how to implement this??

Comment: If that's not what you need, be more specific, show some of the code you have and the result you need.

Comment: What do you mean by need not repeat?

Comment: It means unique for some values of ID_Category

Comment: Am I clear now??...should I add more information??

Answer (score 1):

Using code from http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints

First create this general purpose error table

```
CREATE TABLE `Error` (                                                                                                         
      `ErrorGID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,                                                                         
      `Message` varchar(128) default NULL,                                                                                         
      `Created` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
      on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,                                          
      PRIMARY KEY (`ErrorGID`),                                                                                                   
      UNIQUE KEY `MessageIndex` (`Message`))
      ENGINE=MEMORY 
      DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
      ROW_FORMAT=FIXED 
      COMMENT='The Fail() procedure writes to this table twice to force a constraint failure.';
```

A generic function created to fail

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Fail`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Fail`(_Message VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Error (Message) VALUES (_Message);
  INSERT INTO Error (Message) VALUES (_Message);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now you are armed to create custom constraints on any table, such as yours

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger mytable_check before insert on test.mytable for each row
begin
 if new.id_category in ('list','of','special','categories')
    and exists
      (select * from mytable
       where id_category=new.id_category
         and keywords=new.keywords) then
    call fail(concat('id_category,keywords must be unique when id_category is: ',new.id_category));
 end if;
end $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: what values are present in brackets?------------------new.id_category in ('list','of','special','categories')

Comment: Can u explain this line?----
if new.id_category in ('list','of','special','categories')

Comment: If you want the (category,keyword) to be unique when category is A,B or C, then you use the condition `if new.id_category in ('A','B','C')` etc. If the category is not in the list, the uniqueness is not checked